# TextView not displaying above RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Layout, I have a RadioGroup with two RadioButtons. I have put a TextView on top of the RadioGroup.

But the TextView is not showing up above the RadioGroup. Only the horizontal Radio Buttons are visible.The layout code is as below:-

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarstart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"                
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/east"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/west"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

        </RadioGroup>

     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/radiogroup"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
     android:text="Vehicle Direction"
     />

    </RelativeLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please guide in resolving the issue.

Comment: RelativeLayout is the problem it is overlapping to the appbarlayout, use linear layout or frame layout it will show the textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarstart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="east"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="west"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Vehicle Direction"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/radiogroup" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nilesh. It is working. But can you please explain why my layout code didn't work as intended ?

Comment: @John i have used `pp:layout_anchor="@id/radiogroup"`